# Subtraction order in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, calling-convention, att

So I have.

```
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
movswl 12(%ebp), %edx
movl 8(%ebp), %eax
subl %edx, %eax
popl %ebp
ret
```

If say my function calls 2 variables: `function(int a, short b)`.

When I call the subtraction, would it be `(b - a)` or `(a - b)`. eax is where the value will be stored if I'm correct so I want to say it will be `(a - b)`.

Comment: ISTM that it would be pretty easy to simply try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`movl 8(%ebp), %eax` brings your **int a** in the %EAX register.

`movswl 12(%ebp), %edx` brings your **short b** in the %EDX register.

Since `subl %edx, %eax` subtracts %EDX from %EAX you obtained **(a - b)**